# what's the meaning of different color in FLINK WEB UI

Tags: apache-flink

could anyone tell me what's  the meaning of different color in FLINK WEB UI?
could you list them one by one?
such as:

black:xxxx

grey:

light blue:

blue:

and etc.

Thanks for your help~

[FLINK WEB UI screenshot with colored rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8055a.png)

Comment: are the rectangles clickable?

Comment: yes,i mean the down-right corner of the above picture. for example:green means running....but I don't know the others' meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime-web/web-dashboard/src/app/app.config.ts) are listed the current colors mapping

```
TOTAL: '#112641',
RUNNING: '#52c41a',
FAILED: '#f5222d',
FINISHED: '#1890ff',
CANCELED: '#fa8c16',
CANCELING: '#faad14',
CREATED: '#2f54eb',
DEPLOYING: '#13c2c2',
RECONCILING: '#eb2f96',
IN_PROGRESS: '#faad14',
SCHEDULED: '#722ed1',
COMPLETED: '#1890ff',
RESTARTING: '#13c2c2'
```

Search in the web `color picker` if you need to translate hex color codes.